# Get stream from webcam with openCV and wxPython

Tags: python, opencv

I have read all three or four *current* threads on this subject that are on the internet, and so far none accurately answer the question.

I am fairly new to wxPython, although I have some experience with FLTK. I am new to OpenCV.

I am attempting to capture an image from a webcam with openCV and paint that image into wxPython. I have had limited success (I can get an image and paint it, but it's faint and not aligned properly). I can confirm that my webcam and openCV are working on their own, because [sample code like this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video) works as expected.

Here is an example of my latest effort, which I've cobbled together from the internet and my own efforts with opencv2.

```
import wx
import cv2

class viewWindow(wx.Frame):
    imgSizer = (480,360)
    def __init__(self, parent, title="View Window"):
            super(viewWindow,self).__init__(parent)

            self.pnl = wx.Panel(self)
            self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.image = wx.EmptyImage(self.imgSizer[0],self.imgSizer[1])

            self.imageBit = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.image)
            self.staticBit = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pnl,wx.ID_ANY,
                self.imageBit)

            self.vbox.Add(self.staticBit)
            self.pnl.SetSizer(self.vbox)

            self.timex = wx.Timer(self, wx.ID_OK)
            self.timex.Start(1000/12)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.redraw, self.timex)

            self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

            self.SetSize(self.imgSizer)
            self.Show()

    def redraw(self,e):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        #print('tick')
        self.imageBit = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.image)
        self.staticBit = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pnl, 
            wx.ID_ANY, self.imageBit)
        self.Refresh()

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = viewWindow(None)
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

OpenCV is not a hard requirement (I'm open to other options as long as the solution is cross-platform. If I'm not mistaken, Gstreamer is not cross platform, and PyGame has been difficult to embed in wxPython, but I'm open to ideas).

wxPython is a hard requirement.

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks promising. I'll still hold out to see if anyone has insight into openCV, but the vlc option is *really* good to know about!

Comment: @bluekid will you convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if OpenCV is not a hard requirement

try libvlc and its python bindigs

https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings

Comment: If you have experience with libvlc+wxPython, maybe you can help me with it?
I have two issues: 
First - We was unable to get its logs out of the console (the app becomes very unstable after [our attempts](https://github.com/Himura2la/FestEngine/blob/vlc-logging/src/main.pyw#L54))
Second - We can't make the video be vertically aligned top. [That's how](https://github.com/Himura2la/FestEngine/blob/master/src/projector.py#L136) I output it. VLC player has such a capabilities, but libvlc occupies the whole given space and centers the video.

Comment: And we found no way to get the windet of the actual video size (of corse we can get the video's dimendions and make a fixed-size panel, but I hope there's a better way)
If you have some answers, please open an issue on the GitHub or write us to Gitter, I really need someone who knows the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this modified code, it should show the webcam image from opencv2 into your wx python environment:

```
    import wx
    import cv2

    class viewWindow(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title="View Window"):
                # super(viewWindow,self).__init__(parent)
                wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                self.imgSizer = (480, 360)
                self.pnl = wx.Panel(self)
                self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                self.image = wx.EmptyImage(self.imgSizer[0],self.imgSizer[1])
                self.imageBit = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.image)
                self.staticBit = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pnl, wx.ID_ANY, self.imageBit)

                self.vbox.Add(self.staticBit)

                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                ret, self.frame = self.capture.read()
                if ret:
                    self.height, self.width = self.frame.shape[:2]
                    self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(self.width, self.height, self.frame)

                    self.timex = wx.Timer(self)
                    self.timex.Start(1000./24)
                    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.redraw)
                    self.SetSize(self.imgSizer)
                else:
                    print "Error no webcam image"
                self.pnl.SetSizer(self.vbox)
                self.vbox.Fit(self)
                self.Show()

        def redraw(self,e):
            ret, self.frame = self.capture.read()
            if ret:
                self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(self.frame)
                self.staticBit.SetBitmap(self.bmp)
                self.Refresh()

    def main():
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame = viewWindow(None)
        frame.Center()
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```